How can I find the initial Database name in AWS RDS
While creating the RDS in AWS, there was a field under additional configuration where I need to set a DB name for the RDS. I did set it up and while trying to connect to the RDS using SQL Ectron, I do not remember the initial DB name. I tried finding it out from my existing RDS and unable to see it anywhere. Any inputs?
Initial database name
I tried searching in the RDS > Databases and didn't find it.

I found where it is. The initial database name doesn't show up in the RDS > Databases > database-1 > connectivity & Security
I had been to the modify button in the top right hand corner and was able to see all the options that I set up earlier but not the Initial Database field. I later had to dig into the configuration and finally found the initial database name that I did setup. Without the initial DB name, there is no way we can connect to SQL Ectron
